# Return location header in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am writing an API for shortening URL and I have to return the following response.

```
request:
GET /:shorten_url
Content-Type: "application/json"

Expected Response:

302 response with the location header pointing to the shortened URL
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.example.com # original url
```

I tried:

```
# shortcode is the shorten url of original url
def get(self, request, shortcode):
    if shortcode:
        try:
            shortUrl = UrlShort.objects.get(shortcode=shortcode)
            originalUrl = shortUrl.url
            response = HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
            response['Location'] = shortUrl.url
            return response

        except UrlShort.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404()
```

Rather than getting 302 status code with location header, I'm redirected to the `url` with status code 200. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is special class for "found" redirect you can use - [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) redirect instead:

```
...
return HttpResponseRedirect(shortUrl.url)
```

Comment: I want to get location header and not get redirected

Comment: please have a look at the response i'm expecting

Comment: But `Location` header actually points browser to perform a redirect: "To ask a web browser to load a different web page (URL redirection). In this circumstance, the Location header should be sent with an HTTP status code of 3xx", so one's you are settings code 302 and location header - you actually should be redirected.

Comment: Did you pasted whole code of `get` method for your view? Do you have other part for  `shortcode` equal `None` scenario?